# How to put static and dynamic number in numberOfSectionsInCollectionView and numberOfItemsInSection?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I have UICollectionView and I would like to put a another Header as sample below (dark blue color). [image]

In numberOfSectionsInCollectionView, I able to get the dynamic header 1 & 2 and CollectionView Cell if I use `distinctNames.count`. and `return [groups[section][@"infos"] count];` in numberOfItemsInSection.

My question is, how can I add in extra header (something like static header as below) / cell in numberOfSectionsInCollectionView / numberOfItemsInSection if I have another section and cell to add in?

Can I use return `distinctNames.count + 1`; for additional header? And how can I set in numberOfSectionsInCollectionView?
Please help. Thank you.

```
- (NSInteger) numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView {
    return distinctNames.count + 1;
}

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    if (section == 0) {
        return 1;
    }
    }
return [groups[section][@"infos"] count];
}
```

Comment: can you please explain more. The question is not clear.

Comment: Hi @Priyal, how can I add in more section and cell (numberOfItemsInSection) other than data from array count?